# Custom fields in fb:request form with FBML on iframes

Tags: facebook, xfbml, serverfbml

I'm converting my FBML app to iframe and I want to pass custom fields by setting fb_protected=true. It used to work on FBML apps. But doesn't work when using the FBML tags in iframe. Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

and/or

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1234567"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

for rendering fbml tags you need to import fb js , that is

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

that div tag is reqiured else it will throw an error.

And use `FB.XFBML.parse();` to render your fbml.